# Android ble Broadcast receiver not started in background

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon

I am running my activity and this has a Broadcast receiver which listens to ble updates from a Ble service class. When the device is disconnected when in not in proximity I am using AltBeacon to start my application when the device is in region and it connects to the device. But the Broadcast receiver is not started.

My code is something as follows:

```
class MyActivity{
     onCreate(){

            }
    onResume(){
      registerReciever(....);
     }
    private final BroadcastReceiver gattReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
       onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Please at least provide the `IntentFilter` you are listening to

Comment: It listens to GATT Connections and data from GATT